# Issue updating master pages in InDesign book

Tags: adobe-indesign, master-page

I have the following setup in InDesign CC 13:

- A book.indb with a front matter, several chapters of text, and an end matter, each as a separate .indd document.[image: 1]]
- The front matter is set as style source and contains the styles I need, along with the master pages.
- The front and end matter use no master pages, but all the chapters inherit the ones contained in the front matter.
- The text of the whole manuscript has been segmented into chapters, and so each chapter has its own separate block of text because I couldn't find a way to simply put it all in one place and have it behave properly. I do still have access to the whole manuscript in one piece.

Now, I've already had to readjust the margins of the text once, and so I did that in the master pages, saved it, and synchronised the book. But I found that all the chapters' text frames had basically ignored the changes, and I noticed they weren't set as "primary text flow", so I painstakingly went about fixing this manually for each chapter (even though the master pages were correctly applied to the chapter pages. I thought this had been my mistake or negligence.

But then I had to update the margins again, and, confident that I had already set all primary text flows and everything, I updated the master pages and synchronised the book, only to find that once again the frames had basically overridden themselves. This is what they look like:

[image: 2]]

You can see that the master page elements underneath correctly line up with the page's margins, but the preexisting text frame remained at its previous size and didn't update with the page. The "primary text flow" mark

[image: 3]] has also disappeared without my intervention, while it was there before the synchronisation.

So my question is: what am I doing wrong? How can I correctly update the layout of the book without having to adjust it manually in every single chapter?

Comment: I seem to recall having been through a similar ordeal. Syncing a master page essentially deletes it and then adds another one in its place, breaking all links to it (and making primary text frames non-primary). I don’t remember how I fixed it, but I remember I was very annoyed.

Comment: Glad to know I'm not alone, at least. If you remember how you solved the problem, please let me know.

Comment: I just got bit by this again too – I’m typesetting a book that needs to be with the printers by Tuesday morning, and I just realised I have to change the book size. Now all my text frames get de-primaryfied. I Googled a bit and found a question asking about precisely this thing on Adobe Support Community… and shortly after realised that _I wrote that question_! The question is [here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign/why-does-syncing-a-book-remove-text-frame-primacy-and-can-it-be-stopped/td-p/9005463), but sadly no solution was ever found. :-/

Comment: At this point I think the only solution is probably a script. Which seems kind of ridiculous considering InDesign isn't exactly an indie program. I wouldn't expect the absence of something so common from them.